# How do I search my MYSQL database from an auto populated drop down menu?

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am a complete newbie, and this is the first post i have made in one of these forums. So if i dont explain myself properly or am not supposed to ask questions like this, then please forgive me and try to be patient with me :)

Basically, i have set up a mysql database and i can populate it from my website. I have created a basic search option where i would like to chose an option from a dropdown and also be able to type in a keyword. I have figured out hte keyword part i am just a bit confused as to how to work the drop down side of things. I have searched the internet for answers but im not sure im using the correct terminology and therefore im finding it hard to sort out this problem.

I have created a basic MYSQL database before and made it work before, so i can only assume the problem is with the auto populated drop down.

Let me explain..... i have a serach page imaginatively titled "Search.php" which contains a form which consists of a drop down menu and a text box (dont worry about the text box - that works fine), the drop down box is automatically populated from my MYSQL databse, and when the form is submitted the results should appar on another page, titled "Results.php". For some reason the values from the drop down do not seem to be being passed on to the "Results" page!

Here is the "Search" page drop down box.

```
<select name="Name" id="Name">
<option>Please select</option>
<?PHP
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{$dropdown .="\r\n<option value='{$row['Name']}'>{$row['Name']}</option>";}
echo $dropdown;
PHP?>
```

This all seems to work fine, it auto populates from my MYSQL database and im happy it works.

---

Here is the "Results" page.

```
<?php 
 mysql_connect('xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'username', 'password') or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); 

 $query = "SELECT * FROM Shirts WHERE Name = '$Name'" or die(mysql_error()); 
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());  

 if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  echo ($row['Name']);
  echo "<br />";
  }
 }
```

---

Shirts = the table name
Name = the column in the table

---

For some reason this only returns the "Empty" fields in my database, which makes me believe that the values from the dropdown box on the "Search" page are not being passed to the "Results" page!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark, given there are pieces of your code missing from the above that would make this much clearer.. but, it would appear you're not actually retrieving the values passed by your form.  These values are not automatically available; you need to get them before you can use them.

As I do not know which method of data passing you are using, try the following:

```
$Name = $_REQUEST['Name'];
```

And put it at the top of your php file which generates the results.

`$_REQUEST` contains the data of both methods `POST` and `GET`, so depending on whatever method you used, it should work.

However, I really hope this website is not live.. it is not only using deprecated functions, but is vulnerable to injection attacks.

I recommend instead of using deprecated `mysql_*` functions, you learn how to use [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).  One of the great features of PDO is it auto-escapes queries, provided you use named parameters.

Comment: your shot in the dark was a bullseye !! thank you so much , i cant believe you a) understood my query, and b) solved it so quickly. you have saved me pulling the rest of hair out and i am very grateful. thank you.    in answer to your other question, the site is not live yet, but now i am very worried about the "deprecated" functions and injection query problems !!! i know realise just how out of my depth i am :) i will look into PDO immediateley so thanks for the massive heads up!  thanks again for replying to my query and solvng my problem

Comment: If that solved your issue you should mark it as he correct answer, he should at least get some reputation for his efforts.

Comment: @user1704825 To accept this answer, click on the outlined checkmark below the down arrow button.  Doing so benefits others as well, as it lets them know at at glance that this issue was solved.  It benefits the asker, giving them rep, and the the answerer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your html `select` should be wrapped in a form with the action to results page, if method is specified on the form it is one of `get` or `post`, if no method property is specified the default is `get`, depeding on that you should use in your query `$_GET['Name']` or `$_POST['Name']` respectively instead of `$Name`

Comment: +1 Also, for specifying that a form is needed, just in case it wasn't there in the first place.

Comment: the code is wrappped in a form, the form is quite large so i dint paste the whole thing into my query. i have tried using get and post for the form but neiter seem to work. Thanks again for your reply , im glad to see that people do actually go through peoples requests